# Pass p12 file without password to L2tp

Tags: 14.04, vpn

I have p12 file which I want to feed to l2tp to create a vpn connection. My file doesn't have any password, but when I try to Import it in Connection settings of L2TP IPsec VPN Manager 1.0.9 I get the window with the password box and I cannot not enter anything there.

As a result I cannot feed the p12 file to the l2tp.

Can anyone help me with that and tell me how to feed password-less file to Connection seettings or how to set a password on my p12 file?

Thanks.

Comment: a p12 file consist of key store , which contains a private key, this key is protected by a password, and the moment you exported that file you introduced a password, it is a standard among apps that manage PKCS#12 files, so i think you should ask this question on security.stackexchange.com where you might find better answer, good luck

Comment: I asked sys admin who created p12 file for me about the pass. He said that he created it without the password, basically pressing enter when prompted for the password. P12 file works great on Windows 7 and 8, but does not work in Ubuntu :( I am using Ubuntu for one week only, so I am not really good in this

Comment: "pressing enter when prompted for the password" does not get you to a "No password" state. it creates an empty password, which you must enter by typing exactly what the file creator typed - hit Enter'

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the bunch of commands that helps to re-create p12 file with password:

First, you need to split p12 into cert and key file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in vpn.p12 -out vpn.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in vpn.p12 -out vpn.key.pem -nocerts -nodes
```

And then combine them together:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in vpn.crt.pem -inkey vpn.key.pem -out vpn2.p12
```

You will be asked for a password, just enter the password you want